# Property must only accept an associative array - PHP OOP

Tags: php, class, oop, backend, associative-array

Hi so this is what i need to do:

First i have a class:

```php
class Product
{
    private $name;
    private $price;
    private $sellingByKg;


    public function __construct($name = null, $price = null, $sellingByKg = null)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->sellingByKg = $sellingByKg;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }
    public function getSellingByKg()
    {
        return $this->sellingByKg;
    }
```

Then i have another class that extends the Products class:

```php
class MarketStall extends Product
{
    public $products;

    public function __construct(
        $products= [],
        $name = null,
        $price = null,
        $sellingByKg = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $price, $products);
        $this->products = $products;
    }
```

What i need to do is the property products must only accept an associative array where the keys of the array are the names of the products and the values of the array will be
objects of the class Product.

Comment: In the constructor, loop through the `$products` array, check if it has the desired structure, throw an `Exception` if it doesn't, then set the array onto the property.

Answer (score 1):

Verify if it is an assoc array. (PHP8+)

```
if (array_is_list($products)) {
    throw new Exception("Assoc array expected");
}
```

But if you are using below PHP8 version, you can wrap up the `array_is_list` function with the `function_exists()` function.

```
if (!function_exists('array_is_list')) {
    function array_is_list(array $arr)
    {
        return $arr === [] || (array_keys($arr) === range(0, count($arr) - 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: `array(2 => 'a', 7 => 'b')` not a list. But it is not associative array.